# Change multiple filenames unix

Tags: unix, rename, filenames

I had to download 15GB of data and for some reason during the downloading process the filenames were messed up in a way so that instead of

```
test_file.txt
```

the filenames are doubled, so it's

```
test_file.txttest_file.txt
```

instead. My only idea was whether there is any way to count the letters and then rename each file with deleting the first/ or second half of the filename? The filenames are not consistent, so for example in the same folder there might also be files named

```
files_are_great.txtfiles_are_great.txt
```

so I'm struggling to find a way to loop over them.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `sed 's/\(.*\)\1/\1/'` will replace all duplicated strings with the single string without requiring a certain part of the file name like `.txt`. It allows spaces in the string.

Example:

```
echo 'abc defabc def' | sed 's/^\(.*\)\1$/\1/'
```

prints

```
abc def
```

Explanation of the `sed` command:

- `^` anchors the pattern to the beginning of the line
- `.*` is 0 or more occurrences of any character
- `\(`...`\)` captures what matches the pattern in between
- `\1` is a reference to the first capture group, i.e. the text that was found before
- `$` anchors the search pattern to the end of the line

This results in a search pattern that matches a whole line that consists of any text followed by the same text.

- `\1` in the replacement is the same reference to the matched text, i.e. a single occurrence of the duplicated text.

Any input that does not match the pattern will remain unchanged.

Assuming you want to rename all files in the current directory you can use it like this

```
for file in *
do
    new=$(echo $file|sed 's/\(.*\)\1/\1/')
    [ "$file" = "$new" ] || mv "$file" "$new"
done
```

As the `sed` command does not change non-matching input, `$new` will be the same as `$file` for file names that don't consist of a duplicated string. This would result in an error message from `mv`. That's why the renaming will be skipped in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
sed 's#\(\.txt\)#& #g'
```

Explanation: using `\( \)` we group the expression which can be accessed using `&`

Demo:

```
echo "files_are_great.txtfiles_are_great.txt" | sed 's#\(\.txt\)#& #g' 
files_are_great.txt files_are_great.txt
```

For renaming:

```
for file_name in $(ls -1 *txt*txt)
do 
new_file_name=$(echo $i |sed 's#\(\.txt\)#& #g'  | cut -d' ' -f1)
mv $file_name $new_file_name 
done
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, the demo works perfectly fine. I made some random ascii files and when I try your foor loop I get the error 'cut: the delimiter must be a single character' and then mv: missing destination file operand after files_are_great.txtfiles_are_great.txt ?

Comment: @sciprtgirl_3000  I have updated the code. Please check now. It should have been `cut -d' ' -f1` I missed the quotes.

Comment: This solution works only for file names `*.txt` that don't contain a space. Instead of  inserting a space and then using `cut` to get the first field you could use `sed` to remove the part after .txt`

Comment: Example to cut off the part after `.txt`: `sed 's/\(\.txt\).*/\1/'`. Instead of `for file_name in $(ls -1 *txt*txt)` use `for file_name in *txt*txt`.